# Issue with .delegate and .closest

Tags: jquery, jquery-delegate

```
$('document').delegate('.seeMore a', "click", function() {
    var $allTabs = $(this).closest('.globalTabs').find('.allTabs');
    $allTabs.slideDown('slow'); 
});
```

The DOM elements are:

```
<div class="globalTabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>some link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>some link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="seeMore">
            <a>some link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabContent">
        some content
    </div>
    <div class="allTabs">
        mutliple links
    </div>
</div>
```

the above function is in an `.each` - so for each `.globalTabs` this function should run.

But it seems to not be finding the elements at all, even when there is only one on the page, the `seeMore a` doesn't have any events tied to it (using visual event to determine).

Thoughts?

(I should mention that bind works, but live does not).

Comment: dont think $('document').. should work..  try $(document);

Comment: ha ha ha. I hate making stupid syntax errors and then missing them completely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need in quotes for [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document) in the first selector:

```
// v------v-------- 'document' should be an object, not a string
 $(document).delegate(".seeMore a", "click", function() { ... });
```